# How to modify the content of this DIV?

Tags: magento-1.9, html

I need to modify the content of this div.
To be exact, I need to change the conntent where it says `<?php echo $html ?>`
However, I don't know where to find the content.
The file path is:

**`src/app/design/frontend/website/default/template/serializedproduct/catalog/product/view/configurable.phtml`**

Also, not very clear about what `getChildGroup()` means?

this is the code:

```
                <div class="product-info 18">
                    <?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
                        <h4><?php echo $this->__('Details') ?></h4>
                        <?php $itemprop = 'itemprop="description"' ?>
                        <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $alias => $html): ?>
                            <div <?php echo $this->__($itemprop); ?>class="info-content"><?php echo $html ?></div>
                            <?php $itemprop = ''; ?>
                        <?php endforeach;?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
```

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Where it says *what*?

Comment: added an image.